# Android: can Android AlarmManager wake up the device to perform the scheduled task?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I need to make an App that set up a calendar for the week,

basically the user will input the  start hour and finish hour  of the activity for the  every day of the week.

He will do only once.

After that set up, the application (I will use `AlarmManager`) will start his activity (continuously play video) at the set hour and finish and the set hour:

Every day of the week;

forever,

without human interaction (of course the phone/tablet must be switched on and plugged to electricity).

**My concern is the following:**

Will the `alarmmanger` be able to actually wake up the device in the morning to start the activity (play the video) without any interaction from the user?

The clever suggestion of using

```
    WindowManager wm = Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Window window = getWindow();  
    window.addFlags(wm.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

Gives me a lot of errors in Eclipse:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes u can i tried something similar to that but not exactly..i tried invoking the device every day at 9.00AM to download the contents i used this piece of code

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();

    wl.release();
```

This was my implementation: 
  Used to set the Alaram

```
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
     calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
     calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
     //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*1, pi);
```

BroadcastReciever:

```
Register BroadcastReciever:
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();
    // Put here YOUR code.

    Intent startAutoSyncService = new Intent(context,
            AppoinmentService.class);
    context.startService(startAutoSyncService);

    wl.release();
```

Comment: thank you very much srikanth. Please when would I need to use this? When I set the alarm? Or at the moment the alarm goes off and starts the activity? Thanks again!

Comment: also on device reboot you need to reset the alarms

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to randomize the time a little bit (+- 10 min) to avoid high workload on the server. (As statet in https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Answer (score 2):

yes alarm is gd option. use keyguard dismiss if the device is locked ..

```
 Window win = getWindow();
        win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

        win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

at the time of invking alarm & starting you video/audio activity or screen which you wants to be at the time of alarm get invoked

also **on device reboot** you need to **reset the alarms**

Comment: good to think about resetting the alarms on Boot !! This would mean clean all the possible pre-exiting pendingintents, correct?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but Eclipse gives me lots of errors when I use your code.... :-(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will, if you use `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` or `RTC_WAKEUP` as the alarm type.

Comment: thank you very much Jong. Please what would be the difference between the two??

Comment: The `ELAPSED_REALTIME` means that the time you pass to `AlaramManager.set` method is is according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime(). `RTC` means that the time you pass is according to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis().