# Using fused google api and pending intent ,updating location

Tags: android, location

Using googlelocationapi ,how to get location updates when app is in background?

I know for this we have to use requestLocationUpdates() in which pending intent is used.But how to implement this, please elaborate with all steps.

### class in which i have used requestLocationUpdates with locationListener which update location only in foreground

```
package learn2crack.marshmallowpermissions;
```

public class Go extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

```
private static int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES = 200;

public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000 * 22;
public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000 * 20;

private TextView timel, tvl, tvla, ip;
private EditText et;
private Button btn;

public String mac;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

private SQLiteDatabase db = null;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.go);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    timel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    tvl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tvla = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(lat VARCHAR,lon VARCHAR,macAd VARCHAR,timelast varchar)");

    if (checkGooglePlayServices()) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        //prepare connection request
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    WifiManager mgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo info = mgr.getConnectionInfo();
    mac = info.getMacAddress();

    ip.setText(mac);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM data", null);
            String all = "";
            c.moveToFirst();

            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                all = all + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lat")) + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lon")) + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("macAd")) + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("timelast")) + "\n";
            }
            // db.close();

            et.setText(all);
        }
    });

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        Log.d("Main", "not called");
        // new SendData().execute();
    }
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex.API).build();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//check  net connectivity
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

//check for google play service
private boolean checkGooglePlayServices() {

    int checkGooglePlayServices = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (checkGooglePlayServices != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(checkGooglePlayServices, this, REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES).show();

        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services must be installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    createLocationRequest();
}


protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
/* Second part*/

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {

        Double longi = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        Double lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String timelu = df.format(c.getTime());

        Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude:" + mLastLocation.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + mLastLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        tvl.setText(longi.toString());
        tvla.setText(lat.toString());
        timel.setText(timelu);

        //kamal asshole's code

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(lat VARCHAR,lon VARCHAR,macAd VARCHAR,timelast varchar)");

        String lati = Double.toString(lat);
        String lon = Double.toString(longi);

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO data VALUES('" + lati + "','" + lon + "','" + mac + "','" + timelu + "')");



        /*String url="kamalag.esy..es/home.php?lat="+lat+"&lon="+longi+"&macid="+macAd+"&ts="+timelu;
        if (!url.startsWith("https://") && !url.startsWith("http://")){
            url = "http://" + url;
        }
        Intent openUrlIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(openUrlIntent);*///
    }

    startLocationUpdates();

}


//database entry

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String timelu = df.format(c.getTime());

    mLastLocation = location;
    Double longi = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
    Double lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Update -> Latitude:" + mLastLocation.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + mLastLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(lat VARCHAR,lon VARCHAR,macAd VARCHAR,timelast varchar)");

    String lati = Double.toString(lat);
    String lon = Double.toString(longi);


    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO data VALUES('" + lati + "','" + lon + "','" + mac + "','" + timelu + "')");

}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.disconnect();
}


//asynctask class to send data in background
```

/*   private class SendData extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream is;
        BufferedReader reader;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        StringBuilder response = null;

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM data", null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        Log.d("Main", " called");


        try {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                String lat = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lat"));
                String lon = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lon"));
                String macid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("macAd"));
                String ts = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("timelast"));
                Log.d("Main", "data inserted");

                String urlstring = "http://kamalag.esy.es/home.php?" + "lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&macid=" + macid + "&ts=" + ts;

                URL url = new URL(urlstring);
                Log.d("error", urlstring);
                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();
                is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String temp;
                response = new StringBuilder();

                while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(temp);
                }

            db.execSQL("delete from data WHERE lat= '"+lat+"'and lon='"+lon+"' and macAd='"+macid+"'and timelast='"+ts+"'");

                return response.toString();
            }


        }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ");
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.

                return null;
            } finally {

                c.close();
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }


       // db.();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}*/
```

}

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827121/google-location-api-request-location-updates-with-pending-intent

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use pending intent for get location in background when using fusedApi.

Below link have good example for the same.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/#0