# wakes up my device from standy mode at a particular time

Tags: android

I m new to android world n m trying to make an app that wakes up my device from standy mode at a particular time. 
I tried a few places where they mentioned about wakelock but this thing just prevents the device from going into standy mode.
I basically want my device to wake up from standby mode.
Like take the example of alarm  clock... once set i can leave it and at that time from standby mode I get to see that the phone is active.
I even tried developer site for android... but it wasn't much helpful!
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: It is very easy try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17543889/3243163

Comment: You need to learn about [setting up alarms](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) using the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). Specifically, you're looking for WAKEUP alarms.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Alarm Manager to schedule a repeated alarm (use RTC_WAKEUP for type parameter).

Then your code will execute even if the device is sleep. but notice that the registered alarm will removed once the device is restarted so you have a re-schedule the alarm again (by listening to boot broadcast)